# How to detect subject area in photography

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, photo

I'm working on project and I've stumbled on a problem that I'm not able to solve.

I need to detect the area of a subject in a photo (I just need to know the area of a subject, what the subject actually is not important).

I've tried using DFT and detecting the sharpness.
This approach works very well for photographs made by high level photographers, however it fails miserably when trying to apply it to the average or low quality photos.

The application I'm working on is meant for average user who mainly takes photos via cellphone, however it should support other types of photos.

Any ideas how would I could solve this problem?

Comment: What you're asking for is segmentation of the part of the image that is in focus.  This is not always possible, depending on the content / texture of that part.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying Find Contours and calculating the area using contourArea function

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html

this is a good example of what you might need.
if this is good enough then the resolution will not effect the result a lot it will be fairly the same

Answer (score 0):

If you know something about machine learning and computer vision,
you can try to implement the work of [what is an object](http://thomas.deselaers.de/publications/).